# Runescape installation attempt on Kali Linux

Tags: installation, kali-linux

I've been recently trying to install my fav game RuneScape on my Kali Linux machine. I know it is possible in Ubuntu, but is there any way of doing it in Kali Linux?

These are the commands that are being used to install RuneScape on Ubuntu machines. But these commands seem to not be 100% supported.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hikariknight/unix-runescape-client 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install unix-runescape-client
```

Comment: Is Wine supported in Kali? Every other distro I've used, I used Wine to install Runescape on it.

Comment: No, you don't need wine, there exists another client, see http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Linux_Native_Clients

Comment: @ThomasWeinbrenner yeah but using Wine allows you to run the official Windows client, which is much easier to install and run the official client for stability.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, Kali Linux is based on Debian not Ubuntu.

[Launchpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchpad_%28website%29) is only used in Ubuntu, but not in Debian.
Since there is no repository for Kali Linux or Debian, you could try to download the package directly from http://ppa.launchpad.net/hikariknight/unix-runescape-client/ubuntu/pool/main/r/runescape/ and install it using
`dpkg -i` (and you might need to run `apt-get install -f` afterwards to install missing dependencies) and hope that the package for Ubuntu works on your distribution.